# Activating a Web-scoped Feature using SharePoint 2010 CSOM fails with ArgumentException on featDefScope

Tags: client-object-model, feature-activation

I'm trying to activate a Web-scoped feature using the Client Object Model in SharePoint 2010. The code works when activating a feature in SharePoint 2013, but when run against SharePoint 2010, I get the following error:

```
Error Message: featdefScope
Stack Trace:

System.ArgumentException: at 
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.ProcessResponseStream(Stream responseStream) at 
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.ProcessResponse() at 
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext.ExecuteQuery() at ...
```

Here is the C# code...

```
using (ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("http://site"))
{
    clientContext.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(userName, password);

    Web web = clientContext.Web;
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

    Guid featureGuid = new Guid(featureId);
    web.Features.Add(featureGuid, true, FeatureDefinitionScope.None);

    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

I can activate the feature through the UI and PowerShell on the same server running the code, and again, this code works when run against SharePoint 2013.

How can Web-scoped feature be activated using the Client Object Model for SharePoint 2010?